# Get first element of each array in a parent array

Tags: arrays, typescript, slice

I have an array of arrays in TypesScript and I want to splice it to get the first element of each sub-array. This isn't that hard of a task but I want a concise way of doing it.

Here is a Python example of what I want in TypeScript:

```py
l1 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
l2 = [i[0] for i in l1]
print(l2) # [1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Did you look at `map()` ? You want more concise than that?

Answer (score 2):

You would use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform each sub-array, passing it a function that takes a sub-array and returns its first element:

```js
const input = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
const output = input.map(subarray => subarray[0])
console.log(output) // => [1, 3, 5]
```